# How to remove empty rows in pentaho report designer?

Tags: pentaho-report-designer

We are using Pentaho Report Designer, after publish the report, We are getting some empty rows  with data rows in report. We don't want that empty rows.

Please  give the solution for remove empty rows in report.

Answer (score 0):

Use the expression formula (green plus sign) for "visible" property on the elements you need, to define the condition under it the components will be visible, so elements that satisfy the condition on expression formula will be visible or not.

You can use it at band level, so, if you wanna hide an entire band (it can be de details band for a specific row) e.g.:

1. Click on the band you wanna hide under certain condition
2. Once the element is selected, click on the green plus sign, and set the expression formula desired to make the band visible e.g: =IF(NA([possible_empty_column]);TRUE();FALSE())
3. voila!